# How much current can a proto board handle?

Tags: current, maximum-ratings, protoboard

I am building a circuit on a protoboard (the type with only copper circles). How much current (DC) can that protoboard handle?

Comment: You can solder a wire on, so that would be the limiting factor. What magnitude of current are you thinking about? Do you mean protoboard with only copper circles, or stripboard (a.k.a. [Veroboard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veroboard)) with copper strips?

Comment: Only copper circles. For instance 3-5 Amps can pass through a conductor made of soldering iron made of double copper strips?

Comment: You have to mention the person you're talking to so they get notified by using @username.

Comment: @just_learning - In a comment, you said: "*For instance 3-5 Amps can pass through a conductor made of soldering iron made of double copper strips?*" Unfortunately that doesn't make sense (e.g. a conductor is not "made of soldering iron" - do you mean, made of solder, or something else?) and then you talk about copper (so you didn't seem to mean solder!), but you say copper *strips* - yet you also said that the protoboard you are using has "*Only copper circles*" and therefore won't be type which has copper strips (a.k.a. Veroboard, as kindly mentioned by *Andrew*). So I am completely confused!

Comment: @SamGibson Ok, I have one of these: https://www.amazon.com/AiTrip-Perfboard-Breadboard-Prototyping-Electronic/dp/B07XYL451Y/ref=sr_1_3?dchild=1&keywords=perfboard&pd_rd_r=da53c417-e4f7-499d-b5d4-23dd5870fcbe&pd_rd_w=R4yb8&pd_rd_wg=2IFdn&pf_rd_p=ff875a9e-7810-43da-bae9-ec4c363817ac&pf_rd_r=W9JEK5A5JTK2PDDJ0BFJ&qid=1592685005&sr=8-3  and I make the conductors with soldering. Can these conductors handle 3-5 Amps? Should I make them thickier? I do not use copper cables/wires...

Comment: As the protoboard in your amazon link is just an array of unconnected pads, it doesn't make sense to ask what current it can carry, as it can't pass any current between pads.  Any current in a circuit you build on it will be carried by the wires you add to build the circuit.

Comment: @just_learning, you do not use blobs of solder to make circuits ... use wire folded around component leads and soldered to the component leads ... the wire can also be next to component leads and soldered ... all depends how secure the connection needs to be

Comment: So, I just solder to the pads a wire that can handle 5 Amps, and that's it? I have seen circuits without wire, and the conductors are made by soldering pads...

Comment: @just_learning Yes, that's it. You can get useful small pieces of wire by saving the component leads that you trim off.